# Gradle Error: Not able to use gradle

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

Installed gradle version 2.10 from using HomeBrew and the Offical Zip file.

Trying to run command: gradle --version (or any other command)

Getting error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.configure(Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.java:42)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:191)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:60)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```